# How to create scheduler in EJB3.1

Tags: scheduler, ejb-3.1

I am new to EJB3 world. I want to create scheduler for file processing in EJB. I tried the following code..

```
package com.fks.nclp.ejb.scheduler;

import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Schedules;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


@Stateless
public class AutoTimerBean {

    @Schedules(
            {
                @Schedule(second="3",persistent=false)
            }
    )   
    public void executeOnEveryTwoSecond(){
        System.out.println("THIS IS TESTING OF EJB SCHEDULER");
    }
}
```

And deployed EAR application on GlassFish3.1. As per my requirement the scheduler should be fired at every three seconds.

But its not happening. Any suggestion ???
Thanks,
Gunjan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. In GlassFish server, we have to create EJB timer service from admin console.

Steps are as follow ..

Go to glassFish admin console -> Go to Configurations
  -> Go to server config -> Go to EJB Container

Here set Timer DataSource =  JDBC Default Resource pool.
  Restart the server.

After adding JDBC default resource pool to Timer DataSource, the scheduler works fine.

Thanks,
Gunjan.